# How to create a JSDoc of ref when using React.fowardRef and useImperativeHandle?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsdoc, react-ref

I'm not using typescript in my reactjs project, but I still want to document my components with JSDocs.

The problem where is that I have a functional component with `React.forwardRef` and I want to create a JSDoc to the ref because I'm using `useImperativeHandle` and passing different values to the ref.

It's possible to document the `ref` using JSDoc to display the methods and properties that I pass in `useImperativeHandle`? If yes, how?

Where is an example of what I want

In a component I use `React.fowardRef` with `useImperativeHandle`

```
export const Foo = React.fowardRef((props, ref) => {

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        myMethod,
        // other methods and properties
    }))

    return <div>{/* ... */}</div>
}
```

And when using the `ref` for that component with `fooRef.current`, I want to see `myMethod` or the other properties when I type `.` or press `Ctrl`+ `Space`.

Comment: were you able to document the props?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I don't know if this is the perfect solution, what worked for me was simply writing a typedef for all the props (including ref), and then passing it to @type property, all in JSDoc.
Here is a snippet that should work:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * @typedef {Object} RefType
 * @property {Object} current
 * @property {() => void} current.methodOne
 * @property {() => void} current.methodTwo
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Props
 * @property {RefType} ref
 * @property {string} value
 * @property {((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined} onChange
 */

/**
 * @type {React.FC<Props>}
 */
export const Input = React.forwardRef((
  props, 
  /** @type {RefType} */
  ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value} />
})

Input.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

Input.displayName = 'Input';
```

So when I then use the component, here is the intellisense I get in VSCode for example:
[Intellisense after using said component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlbQX.png)

The intellisense should work in the entire project.

EDIT: I should explain why I included PropTypes. I faced the same issue to yours, and figured out a solution, but I also needed the dev tools to preserve component name. Dev tools would instead display the `React.forwardRef` instead of real component name. The `displayName` property will do the trick to keep the original name.

EDIT: If you need to have autocomplete inside the component itself, you can do it like image link below. I've updated the code snippet to reflect this.
[Autocomplete on ref argument itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwdgL.png)

Comment: Thanks you so much, I've been looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 3):

Write like:

```js
/** @type {React.MutableRefObject<YourTypeHere>} */
const ref = useRef()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add jsDoc on the function declared on `useImperativeHandle` like this. In my instance, I was using Typescript but I believe you could do the same in Javascript if you add the jsDoc just above the declaration of the function inside `useImperativeHandle`

```
type ComponentProps = {}
type ComponentRefProps = {
    /**
     * here is the description of the function
     * @param param1 
     * @param param1 
     * @returns nothing for now
     */
    yourFunction: (param1: any, param2: any) => void
}
const CustomComponent = forwardRef<ComponentRefProps, ComponentProps>((props, ref) => {
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        yourFunction(param1, param2) {
            
        },
    }), [])
    return <Text>This is a component</Text>
})
```